# different outputs on same query execution in MySql

Tags: mysql, spring

I have written a named query to fetch maximum school code(type=String) but when I run the query on MySQL I receive a different output then the one I receive on running my application in spring. For reference I have attached my query.

```
<sql-query name="getMaxSchoolCodeBySchoolCategoryId">
    <return-scalar type="string" column="maxCode" />
    SELECT MAX(sc.`schoolCode`) AS maxCode FROM `School` sc WHERE sc.`schoolCategoryId` IN (:schoolCategoryId) AND 
LENGTH(sc.`schoolCode`)=(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(sc.`schoolCode`)) FROM `School` sc WHERE sc.`schoolCategoryId` IN (:schoolCategoryId))
    </sql-query>
```

Comment: A few questions: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database on both occasions? Which of the 2 executions returns the correct answer? The schoolcode seems to be a string or is it a digit? If it's a string, it could indicate a different locale (with a different sort order)

Comment: yes, i have been connecting to the same database. The query when executed on mySql returns the correct answer and school code is a string